Clarification of ownership with slices
In the rust book they give the following example
fn main() {
    let mut s = String::from("hello world");

    let word = first_word(&s); 

    s.clear(); 
    println!("the first word is: {}",word)
}

where first_word is defined by:
fn first_word(s: &String) -> &str {
    let bytes = s.as_bytes();

    for (i, &item) in bytes.iter().enumerate() {
        if item == b' ' {
            return &s[0..i];
        }
    }

    &s[..]
}

The compiler error is
   Compiling ownership v0.1.0 (file:///projects/ownership)
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `s` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
  --> src/main.rs:18:5
   |
16 |     let word = first_word(&s);
   |                           -- immutable borrow occurs here
17 |
18 |     s.clear(); // error!
   |     ^^^^^^^^^ mutable borrow occurs here
19 |
20 |     println!("the first word is: {}", word);
   |                                       ---- immutable borrow later used here

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0502`.
error: could not compile `ownership` (bin "ownership") due to 1 previous error

From what I understood about ownership &s makes a reference to s which is then dropped when it goes out of scope. That occurs when the first_word function returns. Then we get a new reference that points to specifically the the first character in memory subject to the slice called word. As I understand it, word and s both point to essentially the same memory block allocated for the string but can point to different addresses entirely. However when s.clear() is called it (I assume) takes implicitly a mutable reference to s called &self. &self points to s but word points to something else. My question is how then are the ownership rules violated. It is my understanding that a mutable and an immutable reference cannot point to the same thing while in the same scope but in this case the immutable reference word and the mutable reference &self should not be pointing to the same thing? In diagram form I have


Side note, first_word should take a &str parameter rather than a &String: https://stackoverflow.com/q/40006219/5397009

@Jmb I think you are right but I was just following the example straight from the book.


It is my understanding that a mutable and an immutable reference cannot point to the same thing while in the same scope

What you say is technically true, but it is too narrow.  Yes, you cannot soundly have a shared and an exclusive reference pointing at the same value at the same time, but that's not the only way to violate the aliasing rule.
When you use one reference to derive another reference, the derived reference cannot have a longer lifetime than the reference from which it was derived.  This is most obvious in the signature of functions.
For example, let's create a function that takes a reference as input and returns a reference:
fn foo(s: &str) -> &str

Because of lifetime elision, this means the same thing as:
fn foo<'a>(s: &'a str) -> &'a str

Cool.  Now let's implement it, but we won't derive the returned reference from the input:
fn foo(_: &str) -> &str {
   "foo"
}

Now let's use it, giving it a reference to a string slice derived from a String, clear the String, then print the returned slice:
fn main() {
    let mut s = "bar".to_owned();
    let y = foo(&s);
    
    s.clear();
    println!("{y}");
}

This should work, right?  And it should even be safe.
However, it fails with the same error:
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `s` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
  --> src/main.rs:9:5
   |
7  |     let y = foo(&s);
   |                 -- immutable borrow occurs here
8  |     
9  |     s.clear();
   |     ^^^^^^^^^ mutable borrow occurs here
10 |     println!("{y}");
   |               --- immutable borrow later used here

The point of this is to illustrate that the body of the function is not considered by the borrow checker. We've told the compiler that the returned reference is derived from the reference contained in the argument s.  The function's signature is the only thing the borrow checker is looking at.
In particular, note that nothing in s points at the same location as y, nor vice-versa.  This illustrates the error in your understanding as quoted at the top of my answer.
Now let's back up and look at the code in your question.  You have a reference to a string slice (word) which is derived from a String (s).  In this case it is actually derived from the reference to s, but, again, what happens in the function doesn't matter.  The signature says the returned reference borrows from the input reference, and that's all that matters here.
Then you attempt to obtain an exclusive reference to s implicitly by calling s.clear() (this method takes &mut self) and then later use word.  This is the violation: word borrows s even though it does not point at the same thing as &s, and you attempt to borrow s exclusively at the same time.
Indeed, this specific example demonstrates exactly why the aliasing rule is integral to how Rust implements memory safety, even in single-threaded code.  If this code were permitted to compile (as it would if rewritten in C++, for example), then accessing the contents of word after s.clear() would be a classic use-after-free bug.
This is the same reason you can't obtain a reference to an element of a Vec and then clear the Vec -- because the reference to the element is derived from a reference to the Vec, the reference to the element borrows the Vec, and clearing the Vec requires an exclusive reference to it.  This completely prevents dangling references to dropped/freed Vec elements in safe Rust code.
